# DB2 Problem inserting data in Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, insert, db2

I need to insert data to 3 tables. I'm trying to use a SP. I know I could use Triggers instead but, for integrity reasons, I can't.

When I execute the INSERT statement in an independient Script, I works fine.
The problem is I'm trying to do the insert statement in the SP but it throws me 
**[SQL7008] error**.

I don't know why it throws me this error only in the SP and not (using the same insert statement) in an independient script.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to provide the DB2 version.
If it's DB2 for IBM i (aka iSeries, OS/400), then:

[Received an SQL7008 error when attempting to INSERT data into an AS/400 table. "REXX variable '' contains inconsistent data".](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21007161)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've read about the solution you proposed. However, outside the SP, it works fine.

Comment: You still hasn't provided your db2 version. If it's db2 for IBM i, then you may have default isolation level set to NC (no commit), and this is why your statements outside SP work. If you don't want to enable journaling for your table, then try to create your SP with 'SET OPTION COMMIT = *NONE'. [CREATE PROCEDURE (SQL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcrtpsf.htm)